# Baking a camera texture coordinate image

Tags: uv, baking

I have a quick baking question - I have a procedural stone texture that I have baked onto a UV unwrapped mesh, and I now want to bake a second time in a way that combines the baked stone texture with a second non-procedural brick texture controlled by noise for masking. Currently, it looks fine in rendered view but I can't seem to get it baking correctly: [image: 3D & UV]

Unfortunately, the only way I can seem to get the brick textures to be the correct orientation since some of my UVs are rotated is by using the camera option in the texture coordinate node, but I think this is what stops the image from baking correctly.

[image: Shader Setup]

Is there a way I can bake a UV image and a camera projected image like this? Or do I need to redo the UVs?

Any help is much appreciated,
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Okay never mind I figured it out! Turns out it was because I had accidentally deleted the camera and it won't work without a camera in the scene.